# C# WPF how to add a column based on the content of the row in view model

Tags: c#, wpf

How can i add a column based on the content of the row in view model?

Like if ColumnA.Content contains keyword A,then the content of the new column for that row is XXX.

In my view model, i have defined a collection:

```
 AllData = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_allData);
```

And i am now binding with datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource ="{Binding AllData}"
```

However, I want to group the data by keywords in different columns, so someone mentioned can calculate the row and create a new column to hold the group data, and then use grouping method that group by the newly created column.Thanks!

Thanks!
Eva

Comment: Please add some runnable sample code you will get the answer you seek much faster.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have anything specific you have trouble with? We are people who don't mind helping you, but we don't write the code for you.

Comment: Do you want to generate a pivot table?

Comment: Hi, I tried to use the <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions> in xmal and the .GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("ColumnName")) in the code to group data. however, i cannot find some related source to group by the content.

Comment: I think it is very good idea to use the pivot table in the following step,, but currently i am trying to display the data with filer and group functions first